# meaning of the phrase "draft and drift"

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

I came across this in the news, and the meaning is unclear to me:

> "*Back in 1909, a layer of bricks was laid on top of the rock and tar surface of the Indianapolis Motor Speed Way. It has been resurfaced several times since then. By looking at a core pulled up from the track, you can see the difference layers of stone and asphalt that were added over the years. From top to bottom, it is like a trip in time down to the 1909 layer of brick at the base. Now that the photos of it has surfaced, they show layer by layer or lap by lap a gripping story you can trakh through the years by following the grooves that paved the way for generations of drivers to **draft and drift** down decades of unrevlimited, adrenaling fueled crossing the line where the rubber meets the road.*"

I know what the words mean by itself, but I have a hard time understanding their meaning there.

Comment: There are many mistakes in the context itself. Was this copied from somewhere, or did you write this yourself, based on what you heard?

Comment: When a racing car is close behind another car, it benefits from the fact that the front car pushes the air aside; the rear car is in the fore car's slipstream, and needs to expend that much less energy. It is said to **draft**. **Drifting** is a steering maneuver around a curve, so that the rear wheels skid through the turn, and the car goes through the turn on an angle.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: I agree. It would be better if he wrote it as an answer, not comment, that would an exhausted answer.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the writer of this drivel has a mere acquaintance with formal English.

The article is about the physical evidence for the history of a venue for racing cars, and core samples from the pavement of a race track are remarkably boring even for enthusiasts of car races. "Drift" and "draft" are terms with defined and specialized meanings in car racing, but those meanings are irrelevant in the context used. So the author is attempting a figure of speech to give the excitement of a car race to pictures of a core sample. Absurd figures of speech are the stock in trade of sports reporters.